# Movie where a guy replaces his blood with another liquid, which makes him stronger, but paler

Tags: story-identification, movie

Watched a movie where a guy replaces his blood with another liquid. The protagonist of the movies tries to fight with him but fails because he has no blood in him but  another liquid. I don't remember it being water but it was some liquid stuff and there's a team doing the same thing. I watched it back in 2008 or 2009.

Replacing blood with that liquid makes them stronger than normal and they become pale it seemed.

The scene I watched was in like space; like on Mars or something with those Mars-looking mountains. There's a girl along with the guy who is normal.

- Movie was more like action/scifi
- The guy look like his age was probably like from 25-32
- She was like a sidekick, like a support role
- It was PG-13 or something similar
- They were dressed like the guy and girl from *Divergent*; actually they are similar to those in the *Divergent*
- They were like some special forces and I don't actually remember the motive.

Comment: Was it set in the future? Medieval fantasy? Present time?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: What kind of movie was it? Action/horror/scifi? What did the guy look like? How old was he? Can you remember the actor? Who was the girl (wife/girlfriend/daughter?) and can you remember what she looked like? Was this a film for adults or kids? Did the scene on Mars involve spacesuits? Why were they replacing their blood with liquid (to fight? To fight against who?)

Comment: action/scifi
probably like from 25-32
she was like a side kick more like a supporter
it was like pg13
yes they were dressed like the guy and girl from *divergent* actually they are similar to those in the *divergent*
They were like some special forces and I don't actually remember the motive.

Comment: You've placed a bounty on this question. Is there nothing else you can think to add to the question itself in the intervening time since you posted it?

Comment: Replacing blood? Blood transfusion type or just some kind of infection that changes blood genetically?

Comment: Blood transfusion.